# AS3: hitTestObject turning up null for no apparent reason

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, null, typeerror, hittest

I'm currently coding a game, and in one part of the code, it's checking to see if the player is close enough to a monster in `mArray` for its health bar to appear. I use `hitTestObject` for this with `var i` incrementing to go through the list. However, I will randomly get this error message:

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
```

After seeing this for the first time, I put the test all under the conditional `if (mArray.length > 0)` to make sure the Array() was filled before even attempting the test... but it still occurs at random times. I even used `trace(i)` to see if it happened on a certain part of the list, but it's completely random each debug session! I know the `player` portion can't be null since it is on the screen at all times during the hitTest, so I'm at a loss for words right now.

The portion of code in question (nothing else is related to this except for the use of `mArray[i]` in different places):

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < mArray.length; i++) {
    if (mArray.length > 0) {

        trace(i); //my attempt to see if it occurred at a specific incrementation of i

        if (player.hitTestObject(mArray[i])) {
            mArray[i].healthBar.visible = true;
        } else {
            mArray[i].healthBar.visible = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Again, it works perfectly for everything all of the time except for random cases it gives me the TypeError. Is this just a hiccup in my code, is there some obvious problem that I'm overlooking, or does the code just like to throwback to `2007`?

EDIT: The debug session ALWAYS points to the line with `if (player.hitTestObject(mArray[i]))`.

Comment: Please post those other uses of `mArray[i]` and in general everything you do with this array.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for some `i` the `mArray[i]` has a null value. Either make sure this won't happen when populating the array or just add extra check in `hitTestObject` line like this:

`if (mArray[i] && player.hitTestObject(mArray[i])) { ... }`

I don't know your game's architecture but maybe it would be more convenient to move the `hitTestObject` test into monster class instead of checking it externally. Typical approach is to have each entity to have some kind of "update" method that is executed once in every game loop.